# how to get value from map in firebase database flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i have a json structure like this

```js
{
  "-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN": {
    "idUser": "4dca8440-a37d-11ec-9c66-9b8f61be17f0", 
    "message": "777777"
  }
}
```

and I wanna use fromJson to save to map,
here is my model:

```
class Message {
  final String userId;
  final String message;

  const Message({
    @required this.userId,
    @required this.message,
  });

  static Message fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
        userId: json['idUser'],
        message: json['message'],
      );


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'idUser': userId,
        'message': message,
      };
}
```

right now I always get null from the help from Frank,

```
final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
Message message = Message.fromJson(data);

print('message value${message.message}'); // here i got null
```

please tell me where is wrong.

---------- **Update** ----------

Hi Frank, firstly thanks for your reply, I will get a stream from firebase RTDB, since the data structure is as displayed above, with the data I got from following method,

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
```

the key from this **data** will be `{"-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN"}`, and value is

```
{
    "idUser": "4dca8440-a37d-11ec-9c66-9b8f61be17f0", 
    "message": "777777"
  }
```

so in this case I need to update the method you showed

```
//**instead** snapshot.children.forEach((msgSnapshot) {
  data.values.forEach((msgSnapshot) {

  final Map<String, dynamic> messageData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(msgSnapshot as Map);
  //i am not sure whether I need to use msgSnapshot.value as Map, since msgSnaphot is already the right Map<String, dynamic> that I can put to fromJson      

  Message message = Message.fromJson(messageData);

})
```

Do I understand correctly? thanks for further info!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question doesn't show how `snapshot` is initialized, but my guess is that it contains a list of messages. Even a list of 1 messages is still a list, so you have to handle that in your code by iterating of the `children` property of the snapshot:

```
snapshot.children.forEach((msgSnapshot) {
  final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(msgSnapshot.value as Map);
  Message message = Message.fromJson(data);

  print('message value${message.message}');
})
```

Comment: Hallo @Frank, thanks for your guidance, could you please check my updates

Comment: You need to loop over the [`children` property of the snapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/children.html).

Comment: Hi Frank, indeed your solution works well, I just dont know why my solution above also have same effect

Comment: Thanks a whole lot, you saved the day :)

Answer (score 2):

I have it setup like this in my case witch works just fine:

```
  static Message model({required Map map}) => Message(
        messageID: map[kModelMessengerID],
        owner: map[kModelMessageOwner],
        type: map[kModelMessageType],
        msg: map[kModelMessageMsg],
        membersIDs: (map[kModelMessageMembersIDs] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((e) => e.toString())
            .toList(),
        createdAt: map[kModelMessageCreatedAt] == null
            ? DateTime.now()
            : (map[kModelMessageCreatedAt] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      );
```

and with how I pass data in to it:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
final snapshot = await ref.child(...).get();

if (snapshot.exists) {
    var m  = Message.model(map: snapshot.value as Map))
} else {
    print('No data available.');
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for your comment, I tried your solution, But unfortunately the var m I got is null or just showed as Instance of 'Message', I guess it is because of my json structure? What do you think, please check my update:)

Comment: Log the snapshot.value, we'll have a better understanding of what's being outputted

Comment: Hi Mohamed the json structure above I posted is the output {
  "-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN": {
    "idUser": "4dca8440-a37d-11ec-9c66-9b8f61be17f0", 
    "message": "777777"
  }
}

Comment: Ah I see then it's essentially a map of a map. instead of map['idUser], it'll be map['-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN']['idUser], try logging map['-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN'] and see if you get the proper map outputted.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks a lot for you quick reply:) Yeah indeed, it works as you mentioned, but since this ['-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN']is random number and maybe changed later, do you think there is a better way to fetch this value instead of directly hardcode the ['-My6relBpWvPaY_I4JvN']

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve a list of maps or a single map?

Comment: i think I want to get a list<Message>, now Im using the method from Frank. it works well

Comment: You can do it by iterating through the map and then iterate that again and apply the model to each sub children. in this way you don't need to know the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should look like this:

`{"userId": "4dca8440-a37d-11ec-9c66-9b8f61be17f0", "message": "777777"}`